# Translation of a paper by Salvatore Pincherle

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis

Anyone know of an English translation of the oft-cited paper "Funktionaloperationen und Gleichungen" by Salvatore Pincherle, Encyklopädie der Mathematischen Wissenschaften mit Einschluss ihrer Anwendungen, Vol. 2 (Analysis), Part I.2, pp. 761--817 (B.G. Teubner, Leipzig, 1904-1016).

This is Pincherle of the Pincherle derivative much touted by Rota in his development of the finite operator calculus and related to the Graves-Lie-Heisenberg-Weyl commutator $[f(D),x] = f'(D)$. Pincherle was praised by Wiener for his axiomatic derivation of one family of fractional calculus operators and was given priority by Mellin and Barnes in the development of the Mellin-Barnes contour integral rep for the hypergeometric functions. Although considered one of the founders of functional analysis, he is somewhat neglected in contemporary literature.

Comment: typically, in cases such as this, you want to first get hold of an OCR-ed text and then feed it to an automatic translator; it's not like you are translating poetry, for a mathematics text that should be sufficient to follow the argument --- do you have the text (I couldn't locate it online)?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I've added a correct reference (the title was misspelled) as an edit pending approval -- perhaps this makes it easier to find.

Comment: There is also Pncherle's Theorem on continued fractions in Jones and Throns' book on the topic, mentioned by Askey and Ismail. J & T wrote, "... S. Pincherle (1853-1936), an extremely prolific mathematician who made numerous other contributions to continued fraction theory."

Comment: P. 223 of History of Continued Fractions and Pade Approximants by Brezinski mentions Pincherle's work on continued fractions and orthogonal polynomials.

Comment: Early Days of Complex Dynamics "makes an interesting case for the claim that Pincherle was the first person to describe iteration diagrams, Julia sets, and the Mandelbrot set."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find an OCR-ed text at [https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN360506208?tify={%22pages%22:[77],%22view%22:%22fulltext%22}](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN360506208?tify=%7B%22pages%22:%5B77%5D,%22view%22:%22fulltext%22%7D). As suggested by Carlo Beenakker in comments, running this through Google translate could be a reasonable start.

Comment: Thanks. From the table of contents alone, it seems more interesting than I originally thought. (I'll have to put the following outlier translation in my blog post on quotes in the sciences and math: "We line him up at this point so that he doesn't seem to have to push his egg any longer." An oblique ref to Sisyphus?)